# Facebook profile page regex excluding dialog|plugins|like pages

Tags: php, regex, facebook, preg-match

I am searching for a regex to find the facebook profile page in a webpage html source. I tried something like the below one and it's not working. I am using php preg_match.

```
(.*)facebook\.com\\/[^(plugins)(dialog)(like)](.*)
```

Comment: the edit by Jav_Rock should be `\/` instead of `\\/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
it matches anything before and after "facebook.com" followed optional by "/" and not followed by "plugin", "dialog", "like"

```
(.*)facebook\.com\/?(?!plugins)(?!dialog)(?!like)(.*)
```

See this [online example code](http://www.myregextester.com/?r=d55a8ef1)

`(?!text)` is positive lookahead regexp. You can read more about this [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your early reply. I have combined and made a new one as per my requirement to work on any profile link and your regex saved a lot of my time as I am having basic knowledge in it. I am adding my regex below, it may be useful for others - (?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?!plugins\/)(?!d ialog\/)(?!like\/)(?:pages\/)?(?:[? \w\-]*\/)?(?:profile.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-]*)?